# Resizing ndarray of images efficiently

Tags: python, opencv, resize

I have an ndarray `I` of 100 colored images, where `I.shape` is: `(100,1,3,100,200)`.

This resizes a single image: `i=cv2.resize(i,(10,25))`, but what is an efficient way to resize all the images in `I`, such that the ndarray shape becomes: `(100,1,3,10,25)` ?

Comment: take alook [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19731584/6222397)

Comment: @HishamKaram Thanks Hisham. Can you please try to edit that code for my problem ? I couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposition using `zoom` function from `ndimage`. The resizing takes about 69ms on my computer :

```
import numpy as np
I=np.random.randint(0,255,size=(100,1,3,100,200),dtype=np.uint8)

from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom
I2=zoom(I,zoom=(1,1,1,1./10,1./8),order=1)
```

Comment: This is a neat solution. It should be: "1./10.,1./8." though. Thank you.

Comment: Oh right, sorry ! Should work for python2 and 3 now.

Comment: This was inefficient when I used 0.5 Million images for a Deep Learning application :(
I wish if you have some hints to speed it up or to paralyze it.

Than you.

Comment: @HeshamEraqi Could you be more precise as to what *efficient* means to you ? 0.5 Million 100x200 8-bit RGB images is **30 Gigabytes of data** , that's a lot of calculations and it will require a lot of ram . But as far as efficiency goes I'm really not sure what you are after ... From tests on my laptop the resizing of 20K picture (1.2GB) takes about 12.5 seconds so your 0.5M woud take about 5 minutes to process, is that not fast enough to you?

Comment: Efficiency means faster in that case. Given the fact that an image takes 69ms to be zoomed, it would take 9.5 hours to zoom 0.5M images. I was looking for a more efficient solution, but as I couldn't, I would accept this answer as best answer. Now, I'm doing it on multiple CPU cores to make it even faster using: pool.map(preprocess_images, [imgs for imgs in chunks]).

Comment: @HeshamEraqi Actually the code is resizing **one *hundred* images in 69ms** so it would take **5 or 6 minutes to resize 0.5M images**

Comment: I missed that in my calculations, you are right. Thank you.