# Convert opencv image format to PIL image format?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, type-conversion, python-imaging-library

I want to convert an image loaded

```
TestPicture = cv2.imread("flowers.jpg")
```

I would like to run a [PIL filter](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/ImageFilter.html) like on the [example](https://wellfire.co/learn/python-image-enhancements/) with the variable

```
TestPicture
```

but I'm unable to convert it back and forth between these types.

- Is there a way to do these conversions?
- Can OpenCV do all of the image filters that are in the PIL package?

Example:

[image]

Result:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshold_img = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
im_pil = cv2_to_pil(threshold_img)
pytesseract.image_to_string(im_pil)
Out[5]: 'TUM'
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Yes OpenCV is more robust and flexible and can perform most of the image processing routines which are available out there, So probably this filter can be done with OpenCV> However, there may not be a straightforward API for that.

Anyways, as far as the conversion of image format from OpenCV to PIL is concerned you may use `Image.fromarray` as:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread("path/to/img.png")

# You may need to convert the color.
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im_pil = Image.fromarray(img)

# For reversing the operation:
im_np = np.asarray(im_pil)
```

But you must keep in mind that, OpenCV follows `BGR` convention and `PIL` follows `RGB` color convention, so to keep the things consistent you may need to do use `cv2.cvtColor()` before conversion.

Comment: No required to convert RGB2BGR from im_pil?

Comment: “OpenCV […] can perform most of the image processing routines which are available out there.” — Not by a long shot!

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo, It was w.r.t PIL.

Answer (score 47):

`Pillow` and `OpenCV` use different formats of images. So you can't just read an image in `Pillow` and manipulate it into an OpenCV image.
Pillow uses the `RGB` format as @ZdaR highlighted, and `OpenCV` uses the `BGR` format. So, you need a converter to convert from one format to another.

**To convert from `PIL` image to `OpenCV` use:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

pil_image=Image.open("demo2.jpg") # open image using PIL

# use numpy to convert the pil_image into a numpy array
numpy_image=numpy.array(pil_img)  

# convert to a openCV2 image, notice the COLOR_RGB2BGR which means that 
# the color is converted from RGB to BGR format
opencv_image=cv2.cvtColor(numpy_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

**To convert from `OpenCV` image to `PIL` image use:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

opencv_image=cv2.imread("demo2.jpg") # open image using openCV2

# convert from openCV2 to PIL. Notice the COLOR_BGR2RGB which means that 
# the color is converted from BGR to RGB
color_converted = cv2.cvtColor(opencv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
pil_image=Image.fromarray(color_converted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two functions to convert image between PIL and OpenCV:

```
def toImgOpenCV(imgPIL): # Conver imgPIL to imgOpenCV
    i = np.array(imgPIL) # After mapping from PIL to numpy : [R,G,B,A]
                         # numpy Image Channel system: [B,G,R,A]
    red = i[:,:,0].copy(); i[:,:,0] = i[:,:,2].copy(); i[:,:,2] = red;
    return i; 

def toImgPIL(imgOpenCV): return Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(imgOpenCV, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB));
```

**Convert from OpenCV img to PIL img will lost transparent channel. While convert PIL img to OpenCV img will able to keep transparent channel, although cv2.imshow not display it but save as png will gave result normally.**

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [ZdaR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43234001/15329637), if you want to convert a opencv mask to a pil mask, then simply do:

```
from PIL import Image

PilMask = Image.fromarray(Mask)
```

Im my own program, `PilMask.mode` show me 'L'.