# How possibly can I use the frames generated from my webcam to be the input of my Keras model?

Tags: python, opencv, keras

I want to change the `img_path` to the frames generated from opencv:

```
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
```

How can I rewrite it?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the `image.load_img()` function that you are using is the one from [keras_utils](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/load_img) package.

As it is noted in the documentation, `load_img()` accepts *path* to the image as the first parameter and returns:

> Returns:
> A PIL Image instance.

It is not mentioned in the question, but if you read the frames from the camera using opencv they should already be numpy arrays which you could to pass to your model. Of course you should resize them to (224,224) before ([how to resize the image using opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195453/how-to-resize-an-image-with-opencv2-0-and-python2-6)).

However, if you want to have the PIL images (to have the same type as the one returned by `load_img()`), you need to convert your opencv frames (numpy array) to PIL image. Follow this [question and answer by @ZdaR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232813/convert-opencv-image-format-to-pil-image-format)  to do this conversion:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread("path/to/img.png")

# You may need to convert the color.
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im_pil = Image.fromarray(img)

# For reversing the operation:
im_np = np.asarray(im_pil)
```

Comment: Sorry I had to mention that I am getting the frames cv2.VideoCapture(0).

Comment: If your opened object is `cap`, it will be `ret, frame = cap.read(); if ret: # do something with frame`

Comment: thank you, now how to draw boxes for the objects?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) tutorial to understand how to draw different shapes in opencv