# Take an image directory and resize all images in the directory

Tags: python, image, image-resizing, python-3.7

I am trying to convert high resolution images to something more manageable for machine learning. Currently I have the code to resize the images to what ever height and width I want however I have to do one image at a time which isn't bad when I'm only doing a 12-24 images but soon I want to scale up to do a few hundred images. 
I am trying to read in a directory rather than individual images and save the new images in a new directory. Initial images will vary from .jpg, .png, .tif, etc. but I would like to make all the output images as .png like I have in my code.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

filename = "filename.jpg"
size = 250, 250
file_parts = os.path.splitext(filename)

outfile = file_parts[0] + '_250x250' + file_parts[1]
try:
    img = Image.open(filename)
    img = img.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(outfile, 'PNG')
except IOError as e:
    print("An exception occured '%s'" %e)
```

Any help with this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem your program can only convert one image every time you instantiate it?

Comment: There's a fairly comprehensive analysis of how to do this here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822265/2836621

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the solution you are looking for is to handle multiple images at the same time - here is a solution. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) for more info.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def handle_image(image_file):
    print(image_file)
    #TODO implement the image manipulation here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5) # 5 as an example
    # assuming you know how to prepare image file list
    print(p.map(handle_image, ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.png']))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                  
from PIL import Image                                              
import os, sys                       

path = "\\path\\to\\files\\"
dirs = os.listdir( path )                                       

def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            imResize = im.resize((200,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(f+'.png', 'png', quality=80)

resize()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the contents of a directory with

```
import os

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(MY_DIRECTORY):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('png'):
            #do something
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run through all the images inside the directory using `glob`. And then resize the images with `opencv` as follows or as you have done with `PIL`.

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np

IMG_DIR='home/xx/imgs'
def read_images(directory):
    for img in glob.glob(directory+"/*.png"):
        image = cv2.imread(img)
        resized_img = cv2.resize(image/255.0  , (250 , 250))

        yield resized_img

resized_imgs =  np.array(list(read_images(IMG_DIR)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
dirs = os.listdir( path )
final_size = 244
print(dirs)

def resize_aspect_fit():
    for item in dirs:
         if ".PNG" in item:
             print(item)
             im = Image.open(path+"\\"+item)
             f, e = os.path.splitext(path+"\\"+item)
             size = im.size
             print(size)
             ratio = float(final_size) / max(size)
             new_image_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in size])
             im = im.resize(new_image_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
             new_im = Image.new("RGB", (final_size, final_size))
             new_im.paste(im, ((final_size-new_image_size[0])//2, (final_size-new_image_size[1])//2))
             print(f)
             new_im.save(f + 'resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=400)# png
resize_aspect_fit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to resize multiple images and save them after conversion in the same folder for let's say dimensions of (200,200):

```
import os
from PIL import Image

f = r' '      #Enter the location of your Image Folder
    
new_d = 200

for file in os.listdir(f):
    f_img = f+'/'+file
    try:
        img = Image.open(f_img)
        img = img.resize((new_d, new_d))
        img.save(f_img)
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the PIL library to resize images in python

```
import PIL
import os
import os.path
from PIL import Image


path = r'your images path here'
for file in os.listdir(path): 
    f_img = path+"/"+file
    img = Image.open(f_img)
    img = img.resize((100, 100)) #(width, height)
    img.save(f_img)
```

Comment: I need a code for multipage so that output should also come as multipage tiff image....

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
import os
images_dir_path=' '

def image_rescaling(path):
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_dir=os.path.join(path,img)
        img = Image.open(img_dir)
        img = img.resize((224, 224)) 
        img.save(img_dir)
image_rescaling(images_dir_path)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).