# How to reduce file size of millions of images?

Tags: python, bash, image, jpeg

I have a few million images stored as jpgs. I'd like to reduce the size of each jpg by 80%. Here's a bash loop that I'm currently using (I'm on MacOS):

```
for i in *jpg; do convert "$i" -quality 80% "${i%.jpg}.jpg"; done;
```

The above line converts the images sequentially. Is there a way to parallelize and thus speed up this conversion? I don't need to use bash, just want to find the fastest way to make the conversion.

Comment: Look at [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) . The idea is to share the work between multi process. Each one get a list of file names and work on them on parallel. You will be able to call `convert` from python code

Comment: @balderman is there a python package that offers functionality similar to `convert`?

Comment: Take a look at **PIL**

Comment: I think I would try GNU parallel for a simple shell script.

Comment: @mmz I think the most recent python library wrapper for imagemagick is wand (https://docs.wand-py.org/).

Comment: The premise is fundamentally **incorrect** that specifying `-quality 80%` will reduce the file size by 80%. It could either increase or decrease the file size depending on what the quality was beforehand.

Comment: The idea of starting one **ImageMagick** process for each JPEG file may be completely flawed depending on your disk subsystem and the initial size of your images. You might be significantly better off using **GNU Parallel** with its `-X` option and invoking `magick mogrify`.

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822265/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python you can do it this way:

```py
import glob
import shlex
import subprocess
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import thread_map

def reduce_file(filepath):
    output = f"{filepath}_reduced.jpg"
    cmd = f"convert {filepath} -quality 80% {output}"
    subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd))

list(thread_map(reduce_file, glob.glob("./images/*.jpg")))
```

Given that your images are in `images/*.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Parallelise the execution of `convert` with GNU xargs. This will run 10 `convert` processes simultaneously and restart more processes if less than 10 are running simultaneously until 10 are running simultaneously again.

```
printf "%s\n" *.jpg | xargs -P 10 -I {} convert {} -quality 80% {}
```

`xargs` replaces all `{}` in `convert` command with the file name that comes from stdin.

I assume that your file names do not contain a line break. The original files are overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel convert {} -quality 80% {.}_80.jpg ::: *jpg
```

If the million jpgs are in the same dir, the above line will be too long. Then try:

```
printf '%s\0' *.jpg | parallel -0 convert {} -quality 80% {.}_80.jpg
```