# Convert 5 Mio tiff Files in png

Tags: parallel-processing, png, tiff

i am thinking about the best and fastet way to convert 5 Mio tiff Files (in Folders Subfolders and SubSubfolders) in 5 Mio png Files (same directory).
Is there any way to parallelise this job?

How could i check then if all files are converted?

```
ls *.tif | wc -l # compared to 
ls *.png | wc -l
```

but for every folder.
Thanks.
Marco

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague on details, but you can use **GNU Parallel** and **ImageMagick** like this:

```
find STARTDIRECTORY -iname "*.tif" -print0 | parallel -0 --dry-run magick {} {.}.png
```

If that looks correct, I would make a copy of a few files in a temporary location and try it for real by removing the `--dry-run`. If it works ok, you can add `--bar` for a progress bar too.

In general, **GNU Parallel** will keep `N` jobs running, where `N` is the number of CPU cores you have. You can change this with `-j` parameter.

You can set up **GNU Parallel** to halt on fail, or on success, or a number of failures, or after currently running jobs complete and so on. In general you will get an error message if any file fails to convert but your jobs will continue till completeion. Run `man parallel` and search for `--halt` option.

---

Note that the above starts a new **ImageMagick** process for each image which is not the most efficient although it will be pretty fast on a decent machine with good CPU, disk subsystem and RAM. You could consider using different tools such as `vips` if you feel like experimenting - there are a few ideas and benchmarks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822265/2836621).

Depending on how your files are actually laid out, you might do better using **ImageMagick**'s `mogrify` command, and getting **GNU Parallel** to pass as many files to each invocation as your maximum command line length permits. So, for example, if you had a whole directory of TIFFs that you wanted to make into PNGs, you can do that with a single `mogrify` like this:

```
magick mogrify -format PNG *.tif
```

You could pair that command with a `find` looking for directories something like this:

```
find STARTDIRECTORY -type d -print0 | parallel -0 'cd {} && magick mogrify -format PNG *.tif`
```

Or you could find TIFF files and pass as many as possible to each `mogrify` something like this:

```
find STARTDIRECTORY -iname "*.tif" -print0 | parallel -0 -X magick mogrify -format PNG {}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, and sorry for the delay, i was on holiday … whats about exception handling? as far as i have seen, the convert commands only tell me the name of the problematic file but not the folder, or?