# Error using pytorch-fid for datasets containing 5000 images

Tags: python, bash, pytorch, python-imaging-library, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to calculate the FID between 2 datasets, using pytorch-fid. The GitHub link for the code is: https://github.com/mseitzer/pytorch-fid

**Attempt 1:**
I started off small, with 2800 images, all 512×512, in each dataset. Unfortunately my generated images were PNGs, and the real images were JPGs. So I cd-ed into my generated image folder, ran the following bash script (which uses ImageMagick), and converted all the PNGs into JPGs:

```
for file in *.png
    do convert "$file" "$(basename "$file" .png).jpg"
done
```

With these, I managed to get a FID of 143.6, which I acknowledge is pretty bad.

**Attempt 2:**
I thought increasing the number of images might lower the FID, so I tried again with 5000 images in each dataset. The bash script I wrote above was taking very long to run. So I switched to the Python script below:

```
import os
directory = <PATH TO MY DIRECTORY>

files = os.listdir(directory)


# Then you rename the files
for file_name in files:
    # You give the full path of the file
    old_name = os.path.join(directory, file_name)

    # You CHANGE the extension
    new_name = old_name.replace('.jpg', '.png')
    os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

I later realized this only changes the file extension to '.jpg', and not the file format. This obviously did not work, and I ended up getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to resize storage that is not resizable
```

**Attempt 3:**
I went back to my generated image folder, reversed the code from Attempt 2 (renamed all the JPGs back into PNGs) and ran the script below using Pillow to actually change the file format. Keep in mind, both datasets now have 5000, 512×512, JPG images.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

path = <PATH TO MY DIRECTORY>
files=os.listdir(path)

for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        img = Image.open(path+file)
        #print(img)
        file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        img.save('<PATH TO OUTPUT DIRECTORY>{}.jpg'.format(file_name))
```

But I am still getting the runtime error from Attempt 2. What could be wrong? Is there an issue with the PIL JPG conversion? Should I revert to ImageMagick? Please help!

**Edit:**
I made a silly mistake. I overlooked the fact that a couple of my real images weren't 512×512. I am now able to get a FID of 131.02. That's still pretty bad, but I will continue trying to improve it.

Also, thanks for suggesting multiprocessing. I used it and my conversion process was way faster than before.

Comment: What OS are you using? Which line in your code causes the error? Please provide full stacktrace.

Comment: Did you try my answer at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing 5,000 images, you don't want to pay the start-up time for 5,000 `convert` processes. You would be better to use:

```
mogrify -format JPEG *.png
```

and then you only pay one process start-up cost. However, that only uses a single CPU core, and will probably overflow your command-line length, I mean the `ARG_MAX` parameter. So you will do better to use **GNU Parallel** which will use all your cores in parallel. Depending on your CPU and your RAM and your image sizes, you will likely want a command like this:

```
find . -name "*.png" -print0 | parallel -0 -n 64 magick mogrify -format JPEG {}
```

That runs `find` to identify all the PNG files and send the list to **GNU Parallel** with null-termination so spaces do not upset you. Then **GNU Parallel** will run as many `mogrify` processes as you have CPU cores and pass each process 64 files to convert, which means you will only pay 1 process start-up for every 64 files. It will keep starting new jobs , each processing 64 images as each previous job exits, thereby keeping all your CPU cores busy.

You may need to tweak the numbers and maybe add `--eta` or `--bar` to get a progress bar so you can watch them *"whoosh"* past. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822265/2836621) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70519968/2836621).

---

If you cannot install **GNU Parallel**, at least start each of your `convert` processes in the background, and then add a `wait` after every 4 jobs or so. Something very approximately like this, (untested):

```
i=0
for file in *.png
    do convert "$file" "$(basename "$file" .png).jpg" &
    ((i=i+1))
    [ i % 4 -eq 0 ] && wait
done
```

---

Likewise with your PIL/Pillow code, you should consider multiprocessing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59181995/2836621).

---

As regards the poor results, I suspect JPEG's *"chroma subsampling"* may have affected your results. You could either turn off chroma-subsampling, or try converting with `-quality 90`.