# What's the fastest way to generate millions of png files using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a deep learning project, I need to synthesize plots for each item in my dataset. This means generating 2.5 million plots, each 224x224 pixels.

So far the best I've been able to do is this, which takes 2.7 seconds to run on my PC:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(100):
    fig = plt.Figure(frameon=False, facecolor="white", figsize=(4, 4))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 6, 4, 3])
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    canvas.print_figure(str(i), dpi=56)
```

A resulting image (from this reproducible example) looks like this:

[image]

The real images use a bit more data (200 rows) but that makes little difference to speed.

At the speed above it will take me around 18 hours to generate all my plots! Are there any clever ways to speed this up?

Comment: Could you show the result image for your example? It's not quite obvious how 2x8 values can yield 224x224 px.

Comment: I've added an example plot from the reproducible example code. The real data is a bit bigger (200 points) but that doesn't seem to affect the time much.

Comment: Right - I think using [Pillow's `ImageDraw.line()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html) to draw polylines would probably be much faster than all of the magic MPL has to do.

Comment: I'll give that a try and report back!

Comment: If you are really writing that many files to disk, on a regular basis, you will almost certainly benefit from 1) multiprocessing and 2) an NVME disk to sustain fast i/o.

Comment: The advice from @AKX to use Pillow made things about 6x faster. I've added an answer based off that, but won't accept for now in case anybody else posts.

Comment: I'll try multithreading next. I'll have to do some reading up on the best options for that.

Comment: You might have a look here for some related ideas https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822265/2836621

Comment: After you have 2,500,000 plots, then what? Are you going to look at all of them? Stitch them into a video? At 60 frames/sec, that'd still be a 11.6-hr long video

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment from AKX, Pillow has a function [ImageDraw.line()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html) that performs faster for this task:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from itertools import chain
scale = 224
pad = 5
scale_pad = scale - pad * 2
for i in range(200):
    im = Image.new('RGB', (scale, scale), (255, 255, 255)) 
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) 
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 6, 4, 3]
    x = [pad + (i - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) * scale_pad for i in x]
    y = [pad + (i - min(y)) / (max(y) - min(y)) * scale_pad  for i in y]

    draw.line(list(chain.from_iterable(zip(x, y))), fill=(0, 0, 0), width=4)
    im.save(f"{i}.png")
```

This performs about 6x faster than Matplotlib, meaning my task should take only ~3 hours instead of 18.

Comment: You *might* find it faster to empty your existing image ( e.g. by filling with black) than to create a new one and a new drawing context at each iteration.

Comment: You *may* find it faster to save as JPEG than as PNG, as long as it doesn't upset your downstream processing.

Comment: You can use `Image.paste(0, box=(0,0,w,h))` to fill with black, by the way. Also, if your image has fewer than 256 colours (seems to be black and white), you could try creating it in palette mode, i.e. `P` rather than `RGB`. They will likely take less space in RAM and on disk, which may become important if multiprocessing. Again, as long as it doesn't affect downstream processing.