# best format for saving images to disk so that the loading speed is fastest

Tags: python, pytorch, python-imaging-library

What is the best format to save images to disk so that the loading speed is fastest ?
I am guessing that `.JPG` format might be suboptimal, maybe some other format works better ?

*my case:* I have some 9k `.JPG` images (large 8000x8000 images) and am loading them (using PIL for the moment) for training using `pytorch` on 2x GPUs. I have a large batch size `256` and am noticing that the bottleneck is the loading of these images (which are then resized, augmented and so on)

Anyone knows of any benchmarks on different saving and loading techniques ?

Comment: You can always compress them more to reduce IO overhead. There's no "best" format, it's always about *tradeoffs*. Lower quality = faster loading. Higher quality = larger file size.

Comment: @tadman what do you mean when you say compress them ? just resize to something smaller ?

Comment: I mean JPEG has variable compression, you can trade file-size for quality. It's a "lossy" format meaning if you want them to be smaller, that is an option, but at some point the image will be trashed. Find a good setting here to use.

Comment: I would think that a direct bitmapped image format would be fastest.  Sure, the file itself is bigger, but after reading it, you don't need much postprocessing.

Comment: Some ideas here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822265/2836621

Comment: You can use `libjpeg-turbo`, see https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/5.4.0.html#check-for-libjpeg-turbo

Comment: You can store your images on SSD. You could try multi-threading.