Just keep color range area in images using python
I have high number of JPG images in specific folder that I want to keep only #c7d296 color in my images and fill all other remaining areas in images with white color.
for this I can't use Photoshop because I have high number of JPG images and it get me a lot of time! (about 29000 JPG images).
for this I should use color range tool in python script.
my images are like following sample:

I wrote following script for this process:
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import keyboard

def keep_color_only(input_file, output_directory, color_range, fuzziness):
    try:
        # Read the input image
        img = cv2.imread(input_file)

        # Convert image to HSV color space
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        # Define lower and upper bounds for the color range
        lower_color = np.array(color_range[0])
        upper_color = np.array(color_range[1])

        # Threshold the HSV image to get only desired colors
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_color, upper_color)

        # Invert the mask
        mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

        # Create a white background image
        white_background = np.full_like(img, (255, 255, 255), dtype=np.uint8)

        # Combine the original image with the white background using the mask
        result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
        result = cv2.bitwise_or(result, white_background, mask=mask_inv)

        # Output file path
        output_file = os.path.join(output_directory, os.path.basename(input_file))

        # Save the resulting image
        cv2.imwrite(output_file, result)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {input_file}: {str(e)}")

def process_images(input_directory, output_directory, color_range, fuzziness):
    # Create output directory if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
        os.makedirs(output_directory)

    # Process each JPG file in the input directory
    for filename in os.listdir(input_directory):
        if filename.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
            input_file = os.path.join(input_directory, filename)
            keep_color_only(input_file, output_directory, color_range, fuzziness)

            # Check for 'F7' key press to stop the process
            if keyboard.is_pressed('F7'):
                print("Process stopped by user.")
                return

def main():
    input_directory = r'E:\Desktop\inf\CROP'
    output_directory = r'E:\Desktop\inf\OUTPUT'

    # Color range in HSV format
    color_range = [(75, 90, 160), (95, 255, 255)]  # Lower and upper bounds for HSV color range
    fuzziness = 80

    process_images(input_directory, output_directory, color_range, fuzziness)
    print("Color removal completed.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Note that fuzziness of color range must set on 80
script working good but whole of output images fill by white color. this mean output images just have a empty white screen and no any #c7d296 color area keep!
where is my script problem?

Can you share expected output image?

What OS can you use?

@Alderven you can apply my script on post sample and see output!!

@MarkSetchell windows

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78481661/get-subpath-info-with-python

I know you tagged with python but this is miles simpler with ImageMagick which can be installed on macOS, Linux and Windows for free.
So, basically you want a command like this:
magick 3KPrGAEl.jpg -fill white -fuzz 8% +opaque "#c7d296" result.jpg

That says... "take your input image, and fill with white, anything that is  not within 8% of your green colour in the RGB colour cube, save the result as result.jpg"

In case anyone is struggling with what 8% means, it works like this... The RGB colour cube has sides of length 256. So its diagonal, I mean the line running from pure black to pure white, has length 256 * √3 and that is considered 100% as it is the longest possible distance between two colours. Anything else is a percentage of that length. So, with this method you are using an ice-cream scoop, to scoop out a ball (or sphere) of the radius you desire (as specified by the fuzz) from the RGB colour cube centred on your #c7d296.

Unfortunately, JPEG is a really poor choice for blocky, computer-generated images and it blurs colours and details and makes a heck of a mess, leaving artefacts everywhere. If you could get the images as PNG, you would do better.
Alternatively, you could run a 3x3 median filter to remove small artefacts:
magick 3KPrGAEl.jpg -fill white -fuzz 8% +opaque '#c7d296'  -statistic median 3 result.png


If you need to remove larger artefacts, change the 3 to a 5 or 7. Note though that you will start to lose the edges of your yellow-greenish shape if you do that.

Once you have that command working, you can then adapt it to do all your images, using mogrify. Let's assume you want the output files in a directory called OUTPUT, you can do all your images in one go with:
mkdir OUTPUT
magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -fill white -fuzz 8% +opaque "#c7d296" *.jpg


If you want to speed things up, you should be using all those CPU cores you paid Intel so handsomely for. In general, that means using multi-processing. The simplest way to do that without hand-crafting any code is to use GNU Parallel.
The command would look like this:
parallel -N 10 'magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -fill white -fuzz 8% +opaque "#c7d296"' ::: *.jpg

If that causes errors with too many files, you would need a pipe:
find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | parallel -0 -N 10 'magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -fill white -fuzz 8% +opaque "#c7d296"'

On Windows, you will need to install MSYS2 or WSL to use GNU Parallel.
Or, if your files are named numerically, you can simply do, say 10, parallel processes by picking filenames. For example, if your files are numbered 0..29000.jpg You could do all the files ending in 0 in one job, all the files ending in 1 in another job and so on, running the jobs in parallel:
magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -fill white -fuzz 8% +opaque "#c7d296" *0.jpg &

magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -fill white -fuzz 8% +opaque "#c7d296" *1.jpg &

magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -fill white -fuzz 8% +opaque "#c7d296" *2.jpg &


Note you should consider multiprocessing with your Python solution anyway. Example here.

may I also suggest GNU Parallel, applied to the magick spells. no need to code anything.

@ChristophRackwitz Yes, that's exactly what I was alluding to - and also why I asked about the OS, as it's less obvious on Windows. Thank you. It is actually covered in "Method 3" here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822265/2836621

say, mogrify being a "batch" command, does it perhaps already have parallel capabilities? -- I can use GNU Parallel on my Windows, through MSYS2. -- it doesn't need an entire bash script with a function either. that's "just" convenient to have.

@ChristophRackwitz mogrify doesn't process in parallel by itself AFAIK. I don't use Windows and I believe MSYS2 is a bit of a pain and learning curve, so I rarely suggest GNU Parallel for Windows users, but yes, I agree with you.

aside from MSYS2, there's WSL. a fine environment, 100% linux, with good integration into Windows in both directions. given WSL, installing imagemagick is just the usual sudo apt install imagemagick

good idea - but it is important that can ImageMagick edit 29000 jpg files very soon?

It can, but it depends how your files are named and how keen you are to get it done fast. I will add some more to the multiprocessing part of my answer...

I have added some ideas in for parallel processing to make it really fly.

On my Mac, I can process 29,000 copies of your image in 27 seconds with GNU Parallel.

tnq - I wrote https://pastebin.com/CyZxDrg5 python script for your command and working good :)
