Get SubPath info with python
I have a large number of GIF files that are very similar to the following sample:

Now, I want to create a color range selection with the color #464843 in each GIF file, convert the selection into a work path, and finally obtain information about the subpaths of the created work path.
Note that I have a very large number of files (about 30,000 GIF files) and I cannot use Photoshop for this task!
I want to use Python for this task and have written the following script for it:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def find_extremes(contour):
    min_x = min(contour[:, 0, 0])
    max_x = max(contour[:, 0, 0])
    min_y = min(contour[:, 0, 1])
    max_y = max(contour[:, 0, 1])
    return (min_x, max_x), (min_y, max_y)

def process_frame(frame):
    # Convert frame to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Define color range and apply mask
    lower = np.array([68, 72, 67])
    upper = np.array([60, 72, 67])
    mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower, upper)

    # Expand the selection
    kernel = np.ones((10, 10), np.uint8)
    expanded_mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)

    # Find contours
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(expanded_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Create XML structure
    root = ET.Element("Paths")

    for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
        # Convert contour to work path
        epsilon = 1.0
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
        path = ET.SubElement(root, "Path")
        path.set("name", f"Path_{i+1}")

        # Find lowest and highest points
        extremes_x, extremes_y = find_extremes(approx)
        min_point = ET.SubElement(path, "Min")
        min_point.set("x", str(extremes_x[0]))
        min_point.set("y", str(extremes_y[0]))
        max_point = ET.SubElement(path, "Max")
        max_point.set("x", str(extremes_x[1]))
        max_point.set("y", str(extremes_y[1]))

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    return tree

def save_to_txt(tree, output_dir, filename):
    output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
    tree.write(output_file)

def main():
    # Path to the GIF file
    gif_path = r"E:\Desktop\infon\tst\viopl15.gif"
    # Output directory for the text file
    output_dir = os.path.dirname(gif_path)
    # Output filename
    output_filename = "result.txt"

    # Read the GIF file
    gif = cv2.VideoCapture(gif_path)
    success, frame = gif.read()
    frames = []

    while success:
        frames.append(frame)
        success, frame = gif.read()

    gif.release()

    # Process each frame
    for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
        tree = process_frame(frame)
        save_to_txt(tree, output_dir, f"frame_{i+1}_result.txt")

    print("Processing completed.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Note: The color range selection must expand by 10 pixels using the script.
The script is working, but I don't know why it doesn't get and save any subpath information. It just writes the following in the saved text result file:
<Paths />

where is my script problem?
Note that if there are any other better tools or ideas available, please share them with me.

if there are always only two dominating colours, go with binarizing (e.g. OTSU)

How did you get your color value that you want to use?  When I download your image and get the color of the text, I get #424741, #5e645d, etc.  Namely a wide range of values. You probably need to widen your range of values that you search for using cv2.inRange.  In rgb values, I get a range including at least: rgb(102 107 101) and rgb(72 76 70)

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78476039/just-keep-color-range-area-in-images-using-python

@ChristophRackwitz tnq - I know how to keep only color range area but I don't know how to convert it to work path and get subpaths info!

I understand turning selection into work path - but without Photoshop why do you need them as Photoshop paths? Not trying to complicate the issue, but would an .eps or svg work as well? Also Gimp might be a possibility here.
