More efficent way of hashing a lot of images from urls?
I'm trying to retrieve an image's hash from its url provided in a .json to compare it to a local hash to check for changes.
This seems to be the bottleneck as it only spits out a hash every second when the whole .json has over 3000 image urls that are all ~2400x1600.
import imagehash
from PIL import Image

    def get_hash(image_url) -> str:
        """
        Get image hash
        """

        image_data = Image.open(requests.get(image_url, stream=True).raw)
        hash = str(imagehash.phash(image_data))

        return hash


Is there a way to speed it up?

Use multiprocessing to get them done in parallel. See Method 7 here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822265/2836621

What part of it is slow? Downloading the image over HTTP, loading it with PIL, or generating the image hash?

It seems to be downloading over http, it doesnt seem to be utilizing the full network speed

Please ensure your code is complete and correctly formatted and actually does something - rather than just defining a function you never call.
