# Python barcode library Error

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library

I have installed pybarcode0.6 lib in Windows 7. After installing it, I had written the following code to generate the barcode for my module:

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
import base64
EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('code39')
ean = EAN(barcode_string, writer=ImageWriter())
fullname = ean.save('code39_barcode')
name = open(fullname, "r+")
barcode_data = base64.b64encode(name.read())
```

However when I try to run the code, I got the following error:

```
The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

When I Googled it, I was able to find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011705/python-the-imagingft-c-module-is-not-installed). As per solution given, I have installed PIL lib but I am still facing the same error.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558562/the-imaging-c-module-is-not-installed-on-windows