# Install PIL on Windows 7 64-bit PC

Tags: python, windows-7, installation, python-imaging-library

Python by itself works fine, but when I try to add PIL to it, the installation gives an error message:

> python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry

What can I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088304/installing-pil-python-imaging-library-in-win7-64-bits-python-2-6-4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem had already seen before, it is true that python and windows registry has become problematic for this library, you create a new own registry on the following address `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath` and then copy and paste there the value that is in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath`

Look here for more details

[Installing SetupTools on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652625/installing-setuptools-on-64-bit-windows)

Comment: what if I am using python 3?

Comment: I'm don't sure, however I haven't seen that someone reported it, so if you've already tried, will be great that you add that detail for here, thanks