# How to install Python Image Library on Windows XP?

Tags: python, c, python-imaging-library

This is the link I have downloaded:

> Python Imaging Library 1.1.7 Source Kit (all platforms) (November 15,2009)
>
> http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz

How to execute the `setup.py`?
and i m using Python 3.X

Comment: I found [this][1] here on stackoverflow - maybe it helps!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088304/installing-pil-python-imaging-library-in-win7-64-bits-python-2-6-4

Comment: @seph my installer is not setup.exe, is setup.py

Answer (score 1):

Try Christoph Gohlke's excellent binaries: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil

You have to choose the correct python version and 32/64 bit.